# What's wrong on my file uploading? (Playwright)

Tags: automated-tests, playwright, webautomation

I'm facing with an issue that my files are not being uploaded to website, here is a code:

```
await mainPage.clickElement('locator for the element "Add logo"');
    page.on('filechooser', async (fileChooser) => {
      await fileChooser.setFiles('path to jpg file');
    });
```

I'm using "@playwright/test": "^1.19.2",
why it is not working, what's wrong?
Here is a DOM:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Q48.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr40z.png)

UPD:

```
await mainPage.clickElement('locator for the element "Add logo"');
```

is a simple page.click(), just used from PageObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a race condition. I recommend using the `waitForEvent` function instead:

```
const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForEvent('filechooser'),
  page.click('locator for the element "Add logo"'),
]);

await fileChooser.setFiles('path to jpg file');
```

Comment: oh my god, finally I did it, thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks - this got my plupload-based file upload working nicely.